# How can I block (ssh) traffic from source ports other than a pre-defined one?

Tags: ssh, firewall, port, blocking, firewalld

A VPS get lots of ssh attacks. Those attacks are various *source* ports:

```
sshd[76661]: Invalid user ts3server from 76.103.161.19 port 33062
sshd[76661]: Received disconnect from 76.103.161.19 port 33062:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
sshd[76661]: Disconnected from invalid user ts3server 76.103.161.19 port 33062 [preauth]
sshguard[61313]: Attack from "76.103.161.19" on service SSH with danger 10.
sshguard[61313]: Blocking "76.103.161.19/24" for 86400 secs (1 attacks in 0 secs, after 1 abuses over 0 secs.)
sshd[76821]: Invalid user tibaldi from 140.143.206.216 port 33936
sshd[76821]: Received disconnect from 140.143.206.216 port 33936:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
sshd[76821]: Disconnected from invalid user tibaldi 140.143.206.216 port 33936 [preauth]
sshguard[61313]: Attack from "140.143.206.216" on service SSH with danger 10.
sshguard[61313]: Blocking "140.143.206.216/24" for 86400 secs (1 attacks in 0 secs, after 1 abuses over 0 secs.)
```

As you can see, I currently use a reactive approach (sshguard) in an aggressive way to block and limit those attacks. (Also, no password ssh logins are allowed.) However, there are still too many, so that it floods my logs. What is clear from the logs, is that all these attacks are coming from high-numbered, random ports. What I would like to do is block all that traffic at the firewall-level, so that it doesn't pollute my logs.

I control the client and can choose/define which source port(s) it will use.

Therefore, **how can I block (ssh) traffic from source ports other than a pre-defined one (or range)**?

I'm using firewalld as my firewall management software, so it would be extra helpful if you can provide a firewalld-based solution. However, other solutions are also welcome.

Comment: I think a better approach would be to block SSH from unknown IP addresses and use a VPN to get into your network where you don't have the luxury of a known static IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the **destination** port of a SSH connection typically is 22, the **source** port has (nearly) no rules. This means, that a connection from `140.143.206.216 port 33936` is not suspicous in its own right.

Since I know this problem (Peak was over a million attacks per second on a 10G server) I recommend you use `fail2ban` - this really works.

**EDIT**

After discussion, I understand you control the client. In this case, you can just do something along the lines of

```
iptables -A INPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 '!' --sport 1000 -j DROP
```

(for remote port 1000) will do the trick

Comment: I already use something like fail2ban (i.e., sshguard), but find it insufficient . Also, I should have control over the remote port that I use (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/526745/how-can-i-specify-a-local-port-when-establishing-ssh-connections for example). I will edit the question so as not to refer to ‘the standard port’ anymore.

Comment: The point is: The remote port has no real meaning: You do not chose it, the client dos.

Comment: I can set rules for the client and choose the port it must use. (In fact, in practice *I ‘am’* the only client.)

Comment: You should mention that in the question - it changes the problem fundamentally: An easy `iptables` solves it, if you control the client port.

Comment: I had modified the question after my first comment to your answer. Perhaps it is still not clear? How should I then improve it?

Comment: Still not clear - just mention that you control the client.

Comment: firewalld turns out to be severely limited in its expressiveness combining requirements, so indeed a 'direct rule' appears necessary. This effectively means falling back to iptables syntax as suggested in this answer.

Comment: Just bear in mind that restricting yourself to a single source port means that you can only have *one* SSH session from each host. The 4-tuple (source ip, source port, dest ip, dest port) is what uniquely defines a TCP connection, so each client can have at most 65535 connections to each server, or, in your case, one.